# Debug one function only in liteIDE (golang)

Tags: debugging, go

I was wondering if it is possible inside liteIDE to run only one function, using some parameters, and see what a variable contains after executing one specific code line.

Thanks.

Comment: ...you could write a test for it?

Comment: yup, pretty much what a unit test does - the just `go test` this specific test.

Comment: perhaps someone call tell everyone how to run a specific test in liteide?  (preferably without using the terminal of liteIDE)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I could (and should !) write a test for it.

And for seeing what a variable contains at some step in the execution, either:

- debug-print it inside the function, then run the test
- Use a debugger (for go it's called delve) and step through either the test or the real program

Comment: Thanks @Simon Whitehead, I didn't know what tests were at the time